# Getting the count of occurances from a Group By

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have a table in MySQL

```
 id     hash                              keyword_id
 5      643876315258ecad248bf0de3bff71df    1
 6      643876315258ecad248bf0de3bff71df    4
 15     7ccd09a7b99d386855004a94ef35b42f    2
 16     7ccd09a7b99d386855004a94ef35b42f    3
 17     7ccd09a7b99d386855004a94ef35b42f    1
```

I want to groupby the numberof occurances of keyword_id so my result should look like.

```
keyword_id  occurrences 
1             2
2             1
3             1
4             1
```

I have tried to do this like:

```
select count(Distinct keyword_id) as "Total"
from default_keywords_applied
groupby keyword_id
```

but I'm getting a few errors.

Comment: groupby needs to be group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mysql_query woul be like this

```
select keyword_id,count(keyword_id) as occurance from table group by keyword_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT keyword_id, COUNT(keyword_id) AS occurrences 
FROM default_keywords_applied 
GROUP BY keyword_id
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53268/3)

And yes as [@PeterJ said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889368/getting-the-count-of-occurances-from-a-groupby-in-sql#comment19134337_13889368) there is no space in `group by` in your query.

Comment: Thankyou, I didnt know about sqlfiddle

Comment: @IEnumerable - Yes it's really very good tool. :)